# Getting 404 error on npm install webpack-node-externals

Tags: npm, webpack, npm-install

while trying to install `webpack-node-externals` , I'm getting error:

> npm ERR! 404 Not Found: webpack-node-externals@latest

Comment: Please share the exact command you used to install this package. I just tested and it works on my side.

Comment: npm i webpack-node-externals , This is the command i used to install